# Reading in shell scripting without waiting to hit enter

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm working on a small bash script, and it essentially will just do two things. Execute two update commands together, and list keybinds. In the same way, for example, `chmod +x` would work, `using +x` as a variable. The way I'd like it is if I entered `bash filename.sh -Y`, I would get the keybinds I needed, and if I replaced `-Y` with `-X`, I would have my two update commands running. How would I do this?

Edit; I forgot to mention this, but it honestly doesn't matter if the variable has a hyphen in it. What I mean by the title of the post is, how do I use the `-Y` in `bash filename.sh -Y` without having to hit enter first? Here's the script I'm currently using.

```
#!/bin/sh

read var

if [ var == upd ]
then 
    sudo pacman -Syyu; yay -Syu
fi
```

This works perfectly fine when I input `upd` after pressing enter after running `bash filename.sh`. How would I get the same input with `bash filename.sh upd`?

Comment: Have you heard of `getopts`?

Comment: Reading up on that right now

Comment: Eh, which one do you want? To use the command line arguments, like the `+x` in `chmod +x`, meaning the user would run `bash script.sh whatever<enter>` (or preferably just `script.sh whatever<enter>` after you set the execute permission and hashbang correctly, and place the script in `$PATH`). Or do you want to read input from the user after the script starts, in which case the user would run something like `script.sh<enter>whatever<enter>` (or if you want to read just a single keystrike without enter, you can do that too)

Comment: The first one, yes. I've tried to search for the answer, but haven't really found anything much.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use the command-line argument variables `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, etc. `$1` is automatically set to the first word after the command on the command line. `$2` is the second word. `$3` is the third, etc. You can also use the variable `$#`, which contains the number of arguments on the command line, to see if there are any arguments.

So your script would be:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then
    var="$1"
else
    read var
fi

if [ "$var" == upd ]; then 
    sudo pacman -Syyu; yay -Syu
fi
```

Note: You should ALWAYS put quotation marks around any variable that could contain spaces, especially if the variable might come from user input.

Comment: LinuxSecurityFreak: Your edits were unnecessary. '$#' is *guaranteed* to be an integer and therefore cannot be blank and cannot contain spaces. Also '==' is valid syntax and it helps avoid confusion between comparison and assignment.

Comment: Use at least shellcheck: ^-- SC3014: In POSIX sh, == in place of = is undefined.

Comment: @AndrewVickers, `==` within `[ .. ]` isn't standard shell language, even if it's supported in Bash and ksh. It doesn't work e.g. in Dash, which is `/bin/sh` on Debian and Ubuntu (can't remember about the shells on other OS's). It also doesn't work on zsh, since `=foo` has another meaning there. For `$#`, you'd think it would be safe, since the shell is supposed to reset `IFS` on startup, but some shells don't (at least old versions of Dash and Busybox). And if `IFS` is set to digits, the integer in `$#` will get wordsplit.

Comment: Look, we are here to help, no one knows everything, we are not trying to damage your code, we're doing the opposite, mate. Rolling back our edits does mean you are not exactly perfect syntactically, but that's ok. | -1

Comment: @ikkachu. OK. I get your point. I missed the fact that the OP used `sh`, not `bash`. Probably best to be explicit about the interpreter.

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak. I understand what you are saying, but this is not really helping the OP. Neither is it helpful to downgrade my answer because of disagreements over esoteric issues.

Comment: @AndrewVickers, those esoteric issues come up from time to time on questions here when people think Bash is the only shell in the world, and run `sh somescript` instead of checking what the requirements actually are... I'm not sure it's helpful to propagate non-portable practices, like the `==` here, which has absolutely no upside compared to the more widely supported `=`. I'm also not sure why you insist on quoting the RHS of `var=$1`, when that's one of the rare contexts where the value does not go through word splitting, and the quotes don't do anything.

Comment: But, of course you're free to write your answer as you like, and people are free to vote on its usefulness as they like.

Comment: @ilkkachu. Here is my reasoning:
1) Portability: IMO, for a novice, better to be specific about the shell than trying to cover all possible shells.
2) '=' vs. '==': assignment/comparison bugs are serious, and silent, in most languages. IMO, it is good practice to always differentiate, even when not strictly necessary.
3) Quoting '$#'. You are right. And this is an example of my first point.
4) Quoting parameters. You are right. But for novices, the rule is to *always* quote variables that could contain spaces. I didn't want to confuse the questioner by violating the rule.

Comment: That works for me, thank you!